# How to check the minimum and maximum replica set of Kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, devops, kubernetes-pod

In the yaml file, I have configure the auto-scaling and in this block I've set minimum and maximum replica count, But few deployments are still having 1 pod.
I know this might be due to traffic that those deployments having 1 pod might have less traffic.
Here's the code of the yaml file:

```
 autoscaling:
  enabled: true
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 3
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 70
  targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage: 80
```

But, Is there any command through which I can see the limit of my replicas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
kubectl get hpa -A -w
```

with the `-A` option it gives you all your hpa from all `namespaces` if you want to specify a `namespace`, you can use `-n` option. And the `-w` argument is for watch so you have a refreshed interface that gives you infos on your hpa ressources.